# Unable to stop the function when the condition its true

Tags: c, function, goto

I'm doing a program where you can add items for a shop.  Before the user can be allowed to do that, theres a subfunction which will ask for a user and password; if they are correct then allows the user to add any item as far he wants, also there's a variable called count if this variable goes to "0" should print and error and several noises and after that bring back the user to the main function and close the program.

The problem is after the condition is 0 the noises and error shows correctly but the program backs to ask for user and password and the count variable starts at  0 and every try rest the int...-1 -2 -3.

So I try this, even its working I think it's a pretty bad way:

### The call

```
  while(credencial !=1)
  {

     credencial=checkout(&counter);

     if(counter==88)
     {
        goto error;
     }

  }
```

### Function

```
int checkout(int *counter){

    char login[10], password[10];
    int c = 0;

    printf("\nNumero de intentos restantes: %d\n", *counter);
    puts("\nIntroduce un usuario con credenciales: \n");
    scanf("%10s", login);
    puts("\nIntroduce la contraseña: \n");
    scanf("%10s", password);
    (*counter)--;  

    if (*counter == 0)
    {
       system("cls");
       for (c = 0 ;c < 3 ;c++)
       {
          puts("\n\aACCESSO DENEGADO\n");
       }

       *counter=88;
    }

    if (strcmp(strlwr(login), "admin") ==0 && strcmp(strlwr(password),"admin")==0)
    {
       return 1;
    } 

}
```

Comment: `while((cred >= 0) && (++counter <= 88))`, perhaps?

Comment: Your function does not always return a value.  That's bad; you can't tell what will happen when it doesn't return a value.

Comment: `char password[10]; ... scanf("%10s", password);` is bad.  Buffer too small.  Use: `char password[10+1];`.  Same for `login`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `break;` to leave the while loop (then you need to have a way to decide after the loop if it is a normal or error exit, for example by checking `credential` value) or add an additional condition to the while, like

```
while(credentiel != -1 && !abort) {
....
if (*counter == 88)
  abort = true;
```

Or cou can use the goto, it is not that bad. Especially if the error label is used by other places as well.

BTW: I don't know why you mix out variables with return types and why you use 88 as a special number. Thats all quite untypical. You can keep the counter in the outer loop and make the crendtial check stateless, let it return pass/fail only. It is more common to use negative values (-1) for special "signals". In all cases make sure nobody can force the special value with other tricks.